# Align Integer using cout in C++

Tags: c++, formatting, cout

I need C++ to use cout to print:

```
Header
     1
     2
     3
     4
     5
    10
    11
    12
```

instead of

```
Header
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    10
    11
    12
```

How should I format this using cout?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use the IO manipulator `setw`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Header\n";
    for(int i=1; i<13; ++i)
        std::cout << std::setw(6) << i << '\n';
}
```

Comment: @Mark: Yes, not only can you control width (padding with spaces), but there's also `setprecision` (controls digits after the decimal point).